# How do resistance Ohms work?

Tags: resistors, ohms

So I have been searching on the internet about how to make a homemade resistor and I cam across a webpage which displayed that 8 cm of lead would be 8 Ohms, and then it said that mechanical pencil lead which is usually thinner, would be up to 200 kilo Ohms, so I came to the conclusion that higher Ohms is less resistance, I have found nothing that disproved or proved it. So is my hypothesis correct or have I been wrong for the whole 2 hours of this day?

Comment: How did you conclude that 200,000 is less than 8?

Comment: Since the lead is thinner the current has to go through less material, which it would make sense that it would have less resistance.

Comment: Consider this analogy: Does more water flow through a fat pipe or a skinny pipe?

Comment: If you resist something you don't let it through. More resistance, less current.

Comment: hmm, never thought that electric components could be anologized with things like pipes

Comment: @EnderScythe  Be sure to understand the difference between resistance and [resistivity](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/circuits-topic/circuits-resistance/v/resistivity-and-conductivity).

Comment: Mechanical pencil lead (which is a compund of graphite, kaolin, and binders) is in the order of 1 ohm for 5cm x 0.5mm diameter. A line drawn on paper might have a resistance of 200k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you were wrong. Resistance is the ratio of voltage over current. Higher ohms values mean more resistance.

```
voltage / current = resistance
```

To make things simple, lets say that voltage is going to stay constant (say V = 1). This means that the only way to change current is to change resistance. Lets move things around to make it clearer:

```
voltage / resistance = current
```

A higher resistance gives us a lower current, while a lower resistance results in a higher current:

```
1V / 1ohm  = 1A
1V / 2ohm  = .5A
1V / .5ohm = 2A
```

Now with that out of the way, lets talk about conductors. If you have a very thin wire, there are not very many electrons available inside of it to move around when met with a voltage. To us, this means a higher resistance. In a very thick wire, there are a lot more electrons available, so there is a lower resistance.

This may seem like it's counter intuitive -- surely more material means more resistance -- but that's not the case. You are giving the potential voltage more electrons to move and a larger area to move them in. More electrons means more current.

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense!